# Node.js Error ( Cannot GET /api/events/100 ) ( single Get , Post ) SQL Server 2019

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, api

i create API With Node.js and SQL Server and its working normally with Get All Data I tested it with postman (200)
.. index.js page

```
const getEvents = async () => {
try {
    let pool = await sql.connect(config.sql);
    const sqlQueries = await utils.loadSqlQueries('events');
    const eventsList = await pool.request().query(sqlQueries.eventslist);
    return eventsList.recordset;
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
}
```

}

and the eventController.js page

```
const getAllEvents = async (req, res, next) => {
try {

    const eventlist = await eventData.getEvents();
    res.send(eventlist);        
} catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send(error.message);
}
```

}

and eventlist.sql

```
SELECT [employee_id]
  ,[first_name]
  ,[last_name]
  ,[email]
  ,[phone_number]
  ,[hire_date]
  ,[job_id]
  ,[salary]
  ,[manager_id]
  ,[department_id]
```

FROM [sales].[dbo].[employees]

******************* But with read single post (Error)
index.js page

```
const getById = async(eventId) => {
try {
    let pool = await sql.connect(config.sql);
    const sqlQueries = await utils.loadSqlQueries('events');
    const event = await pool.request()
                        .input('employee_id', sql.Int, eventId)
                        .query(sqlQueries.eventbyId);
    return event.recordset;
} catch (error) {
    return error.message;
}
```

}

And and the eventController.js page

```
const getEvent = async (req, res, next) => {
try {
    const eventId = req.params.id;
    const event = await eventData.getById(eventId);
    res.send(event);
} catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send(error.message);
}
}
```

and eventlbyId.sql

```
SELECT [employee_id]
  ,[first_name]
  ,[last_name]
  ,[email]
  ,[phone_number]
  ,[hire_date]
  ,[job_id]
  ,[salary]
  ,[manager_id]
  ,[department_id]
```

FROM [sales].[dbo].[employees] WHERE [employee_id]=@employee_id

the Res From postman

```
    <pre>Cannot GET /api/events/100</pre>
```

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your filesystem layout, but in `getById`'s definition should `utils.loadSqlQueries('events');` be `utils.loadSqlQueries('eventlbyId');` instead?

Comment: You need to debug your code. First log the error stack in the different catch blocks to see where the problem actually happens.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.